# Auto Hiding Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

I have in my main activity "Toolbar", "TabLayout", "FrameLAyout", and a Fragment that holds a view pager only, and in the fragment code I set the view pager with the tab layout, in the adapter it returns 3 fragments...so the viewpager connected with the tabLayout and has 3 fragment, and it's in seperate fragment, that I replace the "FrameLayout" with it, so the problem I want to make the toolbar hide when any of the view pager's fragment gets scrolled (Like whatsapp and facebook

Comment: show your xml file to better help

Comment: There is an existing view for this in the design support library. Click [here](https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) for more info.